# PHP file upload works with HTTP form but not with Python script

Tags: python, php, html, upload

I'm currently achieving a python project in which I need to have a text file uploaded through HTTP to my server.

At first I was using for convenience an HTTP form and the upload has been working fine.
But now, I want it so I don't have to manually select the file and just have my Python script sending the file for me.

But even if the Apache2 logs indicate that a POST Request have been received by the server while using the Python script, the file is not uploaded.

### PHP

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['filer']['name']);

print_r($_FILES);
echo "<br/>";
echo $uploaddir;
echo "<br/>";
echo $uploadfile;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filer']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "<br/>UPLOAD SUCCESS\n";
} else {
    echo "<br/>ERROR :\n";
}
?>
```

### WORKING HTML FORM

```
<form action='processing.php' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p></p>
      <input type="file" name="filer" accept=".txt" id="file_loader">
      <p></p>
      <a href="https://www.commpro.biz/how-and-where-to-pay-using-bitcoin-in-3-easy-steps/" target="_blank">How to pay in bitcoin</a>
      <p></p>
      <input type="submit" name="send_file" value="Send File ">
    </form>
```

### PYTHON

This script has been tested with httpbin.org/post and I have received only code 200.

```
import requests

with open("987654321.txt", "rb") as a_file:

    file_dict = {"987654321.txt": a_file}
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0','Origin':"http://www.myurl.com"}
    response = requests.post("http://www.myurl.com/processing.php", files=file_dict,headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
    print(response)
```

### APACHE2 LOGS

Here are the server logs. The first line is a successful upload by the HTML form, the second is an unsuccessful attempt from the python script.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2021:09:39:46 +0000] "POST /processing.php HTTP/1.1" 302 562 "http://www.myurl.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2021:09:40:55 +0000] "POST /processing.php HTTP/1.1" 302 523 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
```

Can someone indicates me if I need to change something about the script or the php side to have my file uploaded ?

Comment: If you have a redirect response (302 FOUND status), pythons request object may hide the first response and only show the response from the followed redirect which is counter-intuitive for your analysis. Set allow_redirects to false, it defaults to true. This should give you more insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your file `987654321.txt`, not `filer` as expected:

```
import requests

with open("987654321.txt", "rb") as a_file:    
    file_dict = {"filer": a_file}
    response = requests.post("http://www.myurl.com/processing.php", files=file_dict)
    print(response.text)
    print(response)
```